# PHP MySQL connection in a connection limited environment

Tags: php, mysql, connection

My host limits my concurrent_connections to 70. I have a mock election program that will require 250 students to vote roughly at the same time. The vote process requires 3 pages each with one connection which I kill as soon as the queries are done. Can someone help me come up with a retry algorithm in my conn code please?

```
    $ID_sql = $_POST['name'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error || $ID_sql == NULL) {
        echo "<h1>The system is experiencing too much traffic at the moment, please try again in a few minutes</h1>";
        echo "<a href='index.html'>Click here to go back</a><br>";
        $conn->close();
        die("Connection failed: Congestion" . $conn->connect_error);
        //Instead of die, I would like to try 10-25 times after short sleep() before it dies
        //This should randomize the connections a bit.
    }
```

Comment: 70 connections should easily be able to satisfy 250 concurrent users. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am just trying to avoid collisions or two trying to connect at the same time and having the user not be able to connect.

Comment: Does this actually happen? Do you have long-running scripts? Why are you concerned about it at all?